# Entities design JPA

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

There will be many users and many stores. User can review, make favorite, can rate the store. I have to design entities for this requirement.

I have created User Entity and Review Entity and Store Entity.

Entity design to make store favorite is briefly explained below

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "favourite")
    public class FavouriteEntity{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = true)
    private UserEntity userEntity;

    @Type(type="true_false")
    private boolean value;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "accessory_id", nullable = true)
    private StoreEntity storeEntity;

    public FavouriteEntity(UserEntity user, boolean value, StoreEntity storeEntity) {
        this.value = value;
        this.storeEntity = accessoryEntity;
        this.userEntity = user;
    }    

    }




@Entity
@Table(name = "store")
public class StoreEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<FavouriteEntity> favouriteEntities;

-----------------------------
}
```

Method to make store favorite is below.

```
public void makeStorefavorite(long storeId, boolean val, long userId) {
        StoreEntity accessoryEntity = storeRepository.findOne(storeId);
        UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findOne(userId);
        FavouriteEntity fEntity = favouriteRepository.findAccessoryFavourite(storeId, userId);
        if (fEntity == null) {
            fEntity = new FavouriteEntity(userEntity, val, storeEntity);
        } else {
            fEntity.setValue(val);
        }
        storeEntity.getFavouriteEntities().add(fEntity);
        storeRepository.save(storeEntity);
    }
```

Is it a good design? and when user wants to see all the stores with favorite details, In order to solve this with the current approach , I have to first read all the stores, In each store there will be List of favorite entities, next I have to check for user id among those favorite entities to see user's favorite store or not.

I can solve this issue using `favouriteRepository.findAccessoryFavourite(storeId, userId);` for every storeId I should make a call to DB to get favoriteEntity. from that I can find user made this store favorite or not.

But I would like to know, what is the best approach to solve this?

I have to handle reviews and ratings also for store.

Comment: Just a hint, don't append ``Entity`` to all your entities. This leads to a lot of overhead and doesn't improve readability or comprehension.

Comment: Regarding your design, you should have a ``@OneToMany`` relationship to a FavoriteEntity in your UserEntity, too. That way, you can access the favorites directly without querying the stores.

Comment: Matt thanks for the suggestion.Sorry my actual requirement is I have to list all the stores and show is it user's favorite or not. With your suggestion I have to make first call to get all stores using storeRepository and get all favorite Stores of the user from userEntity. And check stores retrieved by the storeRepository with user favourite stores in nested loop. Is it the best solution or is there any other alternatives.

Comment: You would need to get the stores, anyway. But you could improve the second query to just fetch the IDs of the current user's favorite stores, in pseudo-code something like ``select id from Favorite.StoreEntity.id where Favorite.UserEntity.id = 42``. When listing the stores you just have to compare the store ID with the IDs in your favorite list from the second query.

Comment: Thanks Matt, this is relatively better.

Answer (score 1):

( I dont have enough credits to comment, so I will post this as answer )

You can have this schema.

Consider 4 Entities: UserEntity, StoreEntity, FavouriteEntity, ReviewEntity

```
UserEntity to FavouriteEntity   ---> One to Many (to access all favourites without bothering stores)

UserEntity to ReviewEntity      ---> One to Many

ReviewEntity to StoreEntity     ---> Many to One ( to access all reviews of a store without bothering user)
```

As Matt mentioned, don't append 'Entity' too much. Call them User, Store, Favourite and Review.